# selectedTextRange return nil in UISearchbar iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uisearchbar, uitextinput

I have a`UISearchBar`, I get the`UITextfield` in it and then I want to set selected Text range but it's always return nil. This is my code:

```
UITextField *searchField = [self.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
[searchField becomeFirstResponder]; // focus to this searchfield
```

And I fill in the text:

```
self.searchBar.text = @"This is text";
```

And checked if the`UITextField` text is filled in and it is. Still, all the methods regarding`UITextPosition` and`UITextRange` return nil:

```
UITextRange *selectedRange = [searchField selectedTextRange]; //selectedRange = nil
UITextPosition *newPosition = [searchField positionFromPosition:selectedRange.start offset:addressToComplete.street.length]; //newPosition = nil
UITextRange *newRange = [searchField textRangeFromPosition:newPosition toPosition:newPosition]; //newRange = nil
```

My code is wrong something?

Comment: Are you sure that `searchField` is not `nil`?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure it is not nil

Comment: Read the docs for `selectedTextRange`. It says it returns `nil` if there is no selection. Does the text field have the focus when you call these methods?

Comment: yes, i set focus to this textfield first by call [searchField becomeFirstResponder]; i already update my question. Do you know what's wrong in my code? Cannot understand why it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Logging `UITextField *searchField`? its nil from the looks of it.. i think your code is supposed to be..

`(UITextField *)[self.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"]`

([after trying your code] OooOoKayyy.. it works.. hahaha..) By the way this is how i get UITextField inside searchBar..

```
for (id object in [[[self.searchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews])
{
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        UITextField *searchField = (UITextField *)object;
        break;
    }
}
```

First i tried what you have which is:

```
UITextField *searchField = (UITextField *)[searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
searchBar.text = @"This is text";
// and logging your searchField.text here.. returns nil/empty..
```

and i tried rearranging it like this...

```
 searchBar.text = @"This is text";
 UITextField *searchField = (UITextField *)[searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
 NSLog(@"searchFields.text :%@", searchField.text);
```

again i tried your code under `-(void)viewDidLoad` but no good, yeah it is always nil as you said.. now it looks like this..

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    searchBar.text = @"This is text"; // not important

    UITextField *searchField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    [searchField becomeFirstResponder];

     UITextRange *selectedRange = [searchField selectedTextRange]; //selectedRange = not nil anymore

     NSLog(@"searchField.text :%@ -> selectedRange :%@\n\n" , searchField.text, selectedRange);
}
//i've also tried it inside uibutton's event and i worked .. >.<
```

i programmatically selectedTextRange(for example purposes) and probably it something to do with the xibs autolayout or something (weird i dont experience it) but there it is, try it.. :)

i hope i've helped you..

Happy coding.. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks but it still not working.  i logging the searchfield and sure it's not nil. BTW, my searchbar is outlet from XIB, possible it's the cause?

Comment: @NTNT..  Again i tried your code and yes i also think that it is cause by Xibs auto layout.. Hmm.. i placed your code inside:

`- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
}` i'll edit my answer..

Comment: Thanks. but how do u try on uibutton's event?I write it in 1 event but when call that event, it still show nil. I also tried putting my code in viewDidLayoutSubviews and it worked! so stress ...